# Securing access tokens?

Tags: authentication, web-application

*Preface: I have no experience with securing applications whatsoever.*

I'm building a web app that uses Google Plus authentication to sign users in. My initial thought is to save the access token that gets returned after sign in and store that on my server and use it as an access token for my web app.

I have a concern that this isn't very secure. Anyone who is watching network traffic on my web app can see the token (in headers) and can copy it and form their own malicious calls. Even if the request was encrypted, isn't it possible for it to be unencrypted?

On the other hand, an attacker would need to have their victim signed in already which would imply physical access.

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone who is watching network traffic on my web app can see the token
>   (in headers) and can copy it and form their own malicious calls.

That is correct.  This is why you would want to make sure you use a secure connection (HTTPS in the URL), which will prevent man in the middle attacks.

Comment: What is the likelihood of someone decrypting the request?

Comment: If you are using a secure connection?

Comment: Yes, if a secure connection is used. Or am I just being paranoid?

Comment: Very unlikely, unless you are doing something screwy.